# php restfull Url for API

Tags: php, api, rest

I’m creating  API , I should get the response in the JSON format. I would like to know the best practices and the API should be created.
I have Googled for many REST API tutorials. They were good and I have acquired some knowledge on it, But I want to get a sample model of the code so that I can refer to it and build my own api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see some useful resources here :

- [Building A RESTful PHP Server: Routing the Request](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2012/building-a-restful-php-server-routing-the-request)
- [Creating a Simple REST API](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial-rest.html)

Comment: I will recommend Phalcon.  see it -> http://www.gajotres.net/best-available-php-restful-micro-frameworks/